# Executing background SQL query then update LinkButton with value

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

Currently I have a ASP.NET web form loading and on the page load, I have a sql query that gets some data. The problem is, the sql query is a rather complicated one and it takes upwards of 20-40 secs sometimes to gather the data. This prevents my page from loading quickly. I would like to find a solution to load the bare bones of the page with default values and run the sql query in a seperate thread. Once the query returns the data, I would like to then change the text of some linkbuttons to represent some of the data from the sql dataset. Any suggestions or pointing me to another post would be helpful. Also, example code can be either VB or C#.

Comment: You could create a method and do an asynchronous call to it using ajax once your page loads, and then have that update your page once it returns.

Comment: AJAX is probably the best approach.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it was best to use what @RyanWilson suggested with an asynchronous call once the page loads and then update the page once the query returned data.